Migrate JAXBContext unmarshal to jakarta (without changes e.g. no xml namespaces)
With older Java versions (e.g. 1.8) and the javax packages it was quite easy to load an XML file to Java classes by using
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("my.package");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
MyObject myObject = (MyObject) unmarshaller.unmarshal(in);

There was no hassle with XML namepsaces and similar things.
How it is it possible to achive the same thing with new Java versions (e.g. 17) without changeing the XML file or the Class the data is loaded to? I would also prefer not to use extenal dependecies or stay at least at the most common implementations like jaxb-impl.
UPDATE:
With jaxb-impl I get the error
Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (URI:"", lokal:"MyObject"). Expected elements are (none)
        at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:693)
        at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:230)
        at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:92)
        at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1102)
        at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:527)
        at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:509)
        at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:518)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:731)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3079)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:836)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
        at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:218)
        at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
        at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:152)
        at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:194)
 

UPDATE:
JAXBContext seams to be more picky now. With the change form here JAXB Unmarshalling not working. Expected elements are (none) using JAXBContext.newInstance(MyObject.class) instead of JAXBContext.newInstance("my.package") I get it solved.

"Without changing the Class" : do you also migrate the class with jakarta jaxb annotations ?

Thank you for the comment, in fact I didn't realize that in the mapped class are also the namespace needs to be changed. I will check if that was causing the problem.

But that was not causing the problem. Even after replacing the javax througth jakarta I get the error I added above.

JAXBContext seams to be more picky now. With the change form here JAXB Unmarshalling not working. Expected elements are (none) JAXB Unmarshalling not working. Expected elements are (none) using JAXBContext.newInstance(MyObject.class) instead of JAXBContext.newInstance("my.package") I get it solved.
At the pom.xml I added:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

